# How to hide a video url in asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, video, youtube

I am building a website on asp.net MVC 4. In this website, I will play videos on YouTube with link get from YouTube, and I'll be using jwplayer to play videos.

```html
<script>
    jwplayer("box-live").setup(
    {
        file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-5BEAdzOuY",
        title: "CHAYDAN.COM", width: '728', height: '440',
        logo: {
            link: 'http://chaydan.com',
            //file: '/Content/themes/frontend/images/logo-chaydan-mini.png',
            position: 'bottom.right',
            hide: 'false',
            margin: '-35',
            linktarget: '_blank',
            hide: 'false',
            over: '10',
            out: '0.75'
        },
     });
     function loadVideo(myFile, myImage) {
         jwplayer().load([{ file: myFile, image: myImage }]);
         jwplayer().play();
     }
</script>
```

In javascript, the video url always shows and the end user can view the source website to get the video url. I don't want the users to be able to get this url.

How do I fix it?

Comment: javascript runs at end user's browsers. so it is not possible to hide the video url in your case.

Comment: You can use javascript obfuscator - http://codebeautify.org/jsviewer , http://www.jsobfuscate.com/index.php